# Equivalent of PRAGMA table_info(table) for Postgres SQL?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I am working with a script made for SQLite but I need to adapt it to a PostgreSQL database and this line is always returning an error:

```
PRAGMA table_info(table)
```

How can I get an equivalent result on postgres >

Answer (score 0):

Found it !

```
SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
```